# malloc memory corruption fopen

Tags: c, файлы, apache, apache2, cgi

Запускаю через apache cgi скрипт и на открытии файла код перестает выполнятся и в логи записывает это:

```
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.056137 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: *** Error in `/var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000001c8f0b0 ***: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.056711 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: ======= Backtrace: =========: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.056891 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fa0b92e77e5]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.056992 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8213e)[0x7fa0b92f213e]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057095 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7fa0b92f4184]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057188 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dcdd)[0x7fa0b92ddcdd]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057240 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi[0x400ed3]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057290 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi[0x4016ad]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057338 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi[0x401718]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057434 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fa0b9290830]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057515 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi[0x400db9]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057557 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: ======= Memory map: ========: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057722 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 4981521                            /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057789 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 00604000-00605000 r--p 00004000 08:02 4981521                            /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057850 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 08:02 4981521                            /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057901 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 01c8e000-01cb0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057937 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b4000000-7fa0b4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.057973 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b4021000-7fa0b8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058036 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b905a000-7fa0b9070000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1315327                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058119 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9070000-7fa0b926f000 ---p 00016000 08:02 1315327                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058186 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b926f000-7fa0b9270000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 1315327                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058251 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9270000-7fa0b9430000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1315291                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058317 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9430000-7fa0b9630000 ---p 001c0000 08:02 1315291                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058406 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058477 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9630000-7fa0b9634000 r--p 001c0000 08:02 1315291                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058548 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9634000-7fa0b9636000 rw-p 001c4000 08:02 1315291                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058607 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9636000-7fa0b963a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058671 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b963a000-7fa0b9660000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1315265                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058706 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9835000-7fa0b9838000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058741 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b985c000-7fa0b985f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058804 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b985f000-7fa0b9860000 r--p 00025000 08:02 1315265                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058868 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9860000-7fa0b9861000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 1315265                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058904 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7fa0b9861000-7fa0b9862000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 : /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.058954 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7ffdd0f75000-7ffdd0f96000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.059005 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7ffdd0fb5000-7ffdd0fb7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.059055 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: 7ffdd0fb7000-7ffdd0fb9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.059092 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
[Wed Dec 13 17:24:25.059174 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3316:tid 139914171565824] [client 127.0.0.1:45310] AH01215: :00 0                  [vsyscall]: /var/www/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi, referer: http://eben.my/add_file.html
```

Вот код:

```
#include <ccgi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* pathhome = "/home/rodion/New/";

void add_entry(char* file, char* id, char* entry)
{
    FILE* f  = fopen(file, "w+"); <-- тут вылетает
    if(f!=NULL)
    {
        char* entry1 = calloc(strlen(entry)+strlen(id)+3, sizeof(char));
        sprintf(entry1, "%s|%s\n", id, entry);
        fputs(entry1, f);
        free(entry1);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

int save_image(const char* file, char* id_user, char* id_img)
{
    FILE* ftmp;
    FILE* fimg;
    if((ftmp = fopen(file, "rb"))!=NULL)
    {
        char* path = calloc(strlen(id_user)+strlen(id_img)+20, sizeof(char));
        sprintf(path, "%simages/%s/%s", pathhome, id_user, id_img);
        if((fimg = fopen(path, "w+"))!=NULL)
        {
            char buf [512];
            while ((fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), ftmp)) > 0)
            {
                fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fimg);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        free(path);
    }
    return 1;
}

int add_image(char* id_user)
{
    CGI_varlist *vl;
    CGI_value  *value;
    char* id_img = "1000";

    if ((vl = CGI_get_all("/tmp/cgi-upload-XXXXXX")) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    value = CGI_lookup_all(vl, "image");        //получение изображения

    if(value==NULL||value[0]==NULL&&value[1]==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ai %s\n\n", value[0]);
        save_image(value[0], id_user, id_img);
    }

    value = CGI_lookup_all(vl, "gallery");      // получение id галереи

    if(value==NULL||value[0]==NULL&&value[1]==NULL)
        return 2;

    char* path_gallery = calloc(strlen(id_user)+20, sizeof(char));
    sprintf(path_gallery, "%sgalleries/%s/%s\0", pathhome, id_user, value[0]);

    value = CGI_lookup(vl, "description");  // получение описания к изображению

    if(value==NULL)
    {
        add_entry(path_gallery, id_img, "");
    }
    else
    {
        add_entry(path_gallery, id_img, (char*)value);
    }
    CGI_free_varlist(vl);

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");
    add_image("123");
}
```

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Для начала - почему такой странный способ вычисления длины `path_gallery`? Думаю, если посчитать правильно, то может это и выявит проблему.  В любом случае даже невооружённым глазом видно, что `strlen(id_user)+20` байт недостаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как исправить эту проблему?

Для начала - правильно посчитать сколько памяти нужно выделять для `path_gallery`. Например, так:

```
int size = vsnprintf( NULL, "%sgalleries/%s/%s", pathhome, id_user, value[0] );
if( size < 0 ) /* ... ошибка ... */
char *path_gallery = malloc( size );
if( !path_gallery ) /* ... ошибка ... */
vsnprintf( path_gallery, "%sgalleries/%s/%s", pathhome, id_user, value[0] );
```

P.S. Это то ещё за `\0` в конце строки формата? Не нужен он там:

```
sprintf(path_gallery, "%sgalleries/%s/%s\0", pathhome, id_user, value[0]);
```